# Converting powerpoint .mov to .ts for streaming

Tags: video, ffmpeg, stream

I have a .mov video (powerpoint exported to video) at 0.5 fps, and I want to stream this video:

- stream server: vlc
- stream client: omxplayer (video player for Raspberry Pi)

Currently, I encode every video for streaming like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mov -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 60 -acodec aac video.ts
```

This works fine for any video, except for videos created by powerpoint. Those videos are at 0.5 fps, and it looks like vlc needs at least 10 fps for streaming. So I tried this in order to have 30 fps on the .ts file:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mov -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 60 -acodec aac -r 30 video.ts
```

But it doesn't add frames:

```
[…]
frame=    6 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     193kB time=00:00:06.00 bitrate= 264.0kbits/s speed=9.64x
[…]
```

Creating a .mp4 file works fine, but can't be streamed:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mov -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 60 -acodec aac -r 30 video.mp4
[…]
frame=  360 fps= 52 q=-1.0 Lsize=     314kB time=00:00:11.90 bitrate= 215.9kbits/s dup=354 drop=0 speed=1.71x
[…]
```

I also tried converting this .mp4 video to a .ts for streaming, but the stream doesn't work:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 60 -acodec aac video.ts
```

I found one way to have a working .ts file, but I don't like it. It implies converting the file to raw yuv file, then converting it again to a h264 .ts file. I don't like it because the raw yuv file is really big, and I need to specify the height and width of the final file:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mov -vcodec rawvideo -acodec aac -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 video.yuv
ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s:v 640x480 -r 30 -i video.yuv -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 60 -acodec copy video.ts
```

**So here is my question**: is there a simple way to convert this .mov video to a streamable .ts video ?

Comment: Convert to .ts with `-vf fps=30` instead of `-r 30`

Comment: Thanks @Mulvya ! It's exactly the option I needed. Now it works perfectly !